# How to reinstall Windows 8.1 on MacBook?

Tags: windows-8.1, macbook

I have a MacBook with Windows 8.1 and I want to install a fresh Windows 8.1 installation again.

Comment: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: It is extremely clear what I mean as LukeLR has understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get a Windows 8.1 DVD (if your MacBook has a DVD slot) or USB Stick.
2. Insert the DVD / USB Stick to your MacBook, make sure it's turned off.
3. Press the power button on your MacBook, and immediately hold the alt key after the screen turns on.
4. Select the Windows USB stick from the menu of possible boot media
5. Follow the installation wizard as you would on a regular computer. Be sure to delete all partitions on your internal hard disk, and make one new partition filling the entire hard disk.
6. After the installation is complete, boot up your computer. Check if all of your hardware works (USB, Ethernet, WiFi, Sound, graphics etc.)
7. If not, get the latest version of the Bootcamp Support Utilites from the [Apple Support download page](https://support.apple.com/downloads/boot%2520camp), e.g. [Version 5769](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1837?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) at the present time. These tools are usually downloaded by the BootCamp Assistant, but you can of course download them manually.
8. Unzip the zip archive, and only install the software for the devices that don't work out of the box.
9. Enjoy your fresh Windows install!

Comment: Is it necessary to make one new partition filling the entire hard disk? Isn't a single formatted partition enough?

Comment: @MohsenFarjami - Windows 10 by default will create 3 partitions.  A recovery partition, an EFI partition, and the system partition.  While only 2 of those 2 partitions are required, you are better off, allowing Windows to create all 3.  So is a single partition "enough" absolutely not.

Comment: @Ramhound: But they are created automatically. Just follow my instructions, this will work best. I advised to delete all partitions first and then create a single large one to make sure that a) all contents of the old installation is erased and b) no space is wasted because it’s not used or filled with old junk.

Comment: Why did you direct that comment towards me? I already know how to install Windows on a machine.

Comment: Sorry, that was on mistake :)

Comment: You do not realize that it is **IMPOSSIBLE** to known which Boot Camp Support Software to download or even if the software is available for download without first knowing the model/year of the Mac.

Comment: No, it is nowhere near impossible. Just download the most recent package. Most drivers are identical for all Mac computers (e.g. SuperDrive, Keyboard, Trackpad, Intel Graphics etc.) They contain both support for the most recent models as well as for older models. Some drivers are different, e.g. dedicated graphic card drivers. If the package you downloaded doesn’t include the driver your model needs, then download older ones. But as someone who installed Windows and Linux on many different Mac models without using the Boot Camp Assistant, I can assure you: It is not impossible.

Comment: And do not forget, most drivers are included in Windows or fetched automatically by Windows Update. It’s only for those special Apple devices that don’t get support in the Windows world, e.g. Trackpad or SuperDrive.

Comment: I managed to install correctly without removing other partitions/drives.